# Comment at the end of function move to new line after Alt+Shif+F in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, code-formatting

I would like to put the **function name** as a comment at the end of the function braces.
However, when I use auto-format in netbeans, the comment move to a new line.....

Any suggestion for this case?

Although I would like to post the before-and-after screen shot for your reference, new user are not allow....
If there anything unclear in the question, please feel free to ask me to clear.

Comment: This is a common practce in C. In PHP  If your functions are big try making them small.

Comment: really@@  I just told to add comment after function end when learning C in school....and try to do it on different program language....Orz

Comment: Well in  C, you ave to write more code than any other scripting language and functions are usually bigger. So to trace the start and end this was practiced. But in PHP if you have same degree modularity your functions will be very small. And that doesn't require ending comments.

Comment: Try changing coding style in Tools → Options → Editor → Formatting → Language = PHP

Comment: ic, thanks for explanation. BTW, I have already try to find the solution on changing the Formatting setting but it seem not work~_~

Answer (score 2):

here is link

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

try commenting like this:

```
 /* This is a multi line comment
       yet another line of comment */
```

what are you using the comment for?

Comment: they are same to use // or /**/